# Application (or code) to download full size images from a gallery with thumbnails

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, downloads

For example, [this site](http://www.raagalahari.com/movies/6970/haider-hd-movie-stills.aspx) has thumbnails, and clicking on them loads the full sized image.

Now, the full size images are also embedded in a site that ends with `.aspx`.

So I need an app or code to first scan the thumbnails, then go to the site which has the embedded full sized image and then download it.

I hope someone could help.

I just moved from Windows, so I don't have any apps or software that didn't come along with Ubuntu 14.04. I think from the terminal I have downloaded `wget` (or else it came along with the OS.) Anyway, I had used it once (tried to) for the same task in the question but I don't know what commands to use.

Comment: Actually, in Windows I used a software BulkImageDownloader. But it doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu even with Wine. So I needed an application like that for use in Linux. I was saying "In case" such an app is not available at the moment, a script would do.None of the Mozilla addon seem to work(atleast the ones Ii tried like DTA)

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, write small script to do that.
But I would rather use some existing tools.

Try for example: HTTrack

```
sudo apt-get install httrack
```

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded it but isn't working. ( for this site)